# AG Grid: headerCheckboxSelection is only available if using 'clientSide' or 'serverSide' rowModelType, you are using infinite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, grid, ag-grid

**Problem:**

I am using `rowModelType = 'infinite'` in my React.Js application.

In order to use `headerCheckboxSelection = true` (default checkbox for header) agGrid forces us to use **clientSide** or **serverSide** rowModelType.

So I wrote my custom HeaderCheckbox Component but I am not getting any events in my HeaderCheckbox Custom Component if checkboxes of the rows of the grid changes.

**My Approach:**

I created a custom headerCheckbox Component using `<input type="checkbox ..."/>`
and now I want events in the headerCheckbox component so that I can change the state of header checkbox like 'checked', 'unchecked' and 'indeterminate'.

**Why:**

Because I want to select/deselect all rows using my headerCheckbox component.

**Code:**

*HeaderCheckboxComponent.tsx*

```
function HeaderCheckbox({api}:HeaderCheckbox Type){
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState<boolean>(false);

//want to get events here if rows changed of the grid
console.log('Event Api', api); 

const onChangeHandler = (event: any) => {
 // handle checkbox state
}

<input
 type="checkbox"
 checked={isChecked}
 onChange={onChangeHandler}
/>
```

*columnDefinitions.ts*

```
 export default (data)=>{
  {
   colId: 'id',
   field: 'id',
   checkboxSelection: true,
   headerComponent: HeaderCheckboxComponent,
  },
  {
   colId: "packet",
   field: "packet",
   headerName: 'Packet Details' 
  }
}
```

*MyAgGrid.tsx*

```
function MyAgGrid({grifRef, totalCount, rows}) {
 return(
   <AgGrid>
     gridRef={gridRef}
     rows={rows}
     totalCount={totalCount}
     // import from ColumnDefinitions.tsx
     columnDefs={columnDefinitions} 
   </AgGrid>
   )
}
```